# What does this line of C# code actually do?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I'm trying to understand what a block of code in an application does but I've come across a bit of C# I just don't understand.

In the code below, what does the code after the "controller.Progress +="  line do?

I've not seen this syntax before and as I don't know what the constructs are called, I can't google anything to find out what this syntax means or does.  What for instance, are the values s and p? Are they placeholders?

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    using (var controller = new ApplicationDeviceController(e.Argument as SimpleDeviceModel))
    {
        controller.Progress += 
           (s, p) => { (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(p.Percent); };
        string html = controller.GetAndConvertLog();
        e.Result = html;
    }
}
```

It looks like it's attaching a function to an event, but I just don't understand the syntax (or what s and p are) and there's no useful intellsense on that code.

Comment: Note that since `(sender as BackgroundWorker)` will be null if the conversion fails and will immediately cause a null-reference exception, writing it like this would better express the intent (and give a more meaningful exception if it failed): `{ ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress(p.Percent); }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a lambda expression being assigned to an event handler.

S and P are variables that are passed into the function. You're basically defining a nameless function, that receives two parameters. Because C# knows that the controller.Progress event expects a method handler with two parameters of types int and object, it automatically assumes that the two variables are of those types.

You could also have defined this as

```
controller.Progress += (int s, object p)=> { ... }
```

It's the same as if you had a method definition instead:

```
controller.Progress += DoReportProgress;
....
public void DoReportProgress(int percentage, object obj) { .... }
```

Answer (score 3):

It wires up the `Progress` event of `controller` to trigger the `BackgroundWorker's` `ReportProgress`

More specifically, `(s, p)` is the Method Parameter Signature for the event handler, like `(object Sender, EventArgs e)`

See [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

It's called an [Anonymous Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx).

> An anonymous function is an "inline" statement or expression that can be used wherever a delegate type is expected. You can use it to initialize a named delegate or pass it instead of a named delegate type as a method parameter.

In your scenario, it is basically wiring up your `Progress` event to trigger the `ReportProgess` function.

Normally, it would be written something like:

```
controller.Progress += new EventHandler(delegate (object sender, EventArgs a) {
    (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(p.Percent);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually this code assigns the lambda exp to the event. In compile time it will be converted as delegates as follows,

```
controller.Progress += new EventHandler(delegate (Object o, EventArgs a) {
a.ReportProgress(p.Percent);
            });
```